# Can I edit Apache Solr's managed-schema file manually?

Tags: solr

If I just created a new core with Apache Solr 6.1.0 and haven't added any documents yet, will manually editing the default managed-schema file cause errors down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *managed-schema.xml* could be changed manually and that wouldn't cause errors, however the best practice regardless of the existing documents is to use the API as explained [here](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/221618187-What-is-Managed-Schema-).

Comment: if i changed the _managed-schema.xml_ manually while the server was up, would i have to restart the server in order for the changes to take affect?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the changes won't be applied.

Comment: the link is broken